# how to run Jmeter load test where a Http request is executed n number of time and each time with different parameter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a test plan that has following flow:-

1.)Http request to call the first web service that returns json data
2.) Bean shell post processor to parse the response and create a array and set it in the vars as a key value.
3.) (The problem) For each element in the array a httpt request should be send with that array element as a parameter to the request.

The code for Bean shell post processor is:-

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Random;

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JSONObject response= new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray sba=response.getJSONArray("sba");
JSONArray si_id_list=new JSONArray ();
for(int i=0;i<sba.length();i++ ){
    si_id_list.put(sba.getJSONObject(i).getString("si_id"));
}

vars.put("si_id", si_id_list.toString());
```

Is it possible to use this array to pass input to another http request,one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to amend your Beanshell script as follows:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Random;

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JSONObject response= new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray sba=response.getJSONArray("sba");
JSONArray si_id_list=new JSONArray ();
for(int i=0;i<sba.length();i++ ){
    si_id_list.put(sba.getJSONObject(i).getString("si_id"));
    vars.put("si_id_"+i, sba.getJSONObject(i).getString("si_id"));

}
```

After that you'll have variables like `si_id_1`, `si_id_2`, etc. holding relevant si_id values.

As per [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) you'll be able to utilize JMeter [Foreach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate all members of JSON Array.